# Is there any way to prevent Java from turning my double into exponential value?

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there anyway to prevent Java from turning my double into exponential value?  I am having problem with saving that into my database.  It keep telling me that it can not convert my VarChar into numeric.

I do;

```
amt = oldAmt - amt;
amt = Math.abs(amt);
```

And put the value in **amt** like so using setter;

```
jvd.setDr_amt(amt);
```

Then generate a query string using a function and it give me;

```
INSERT INTO jv ( id, dr_amt) VALUES (1, 1.595545786E7);
```

The datatype in the database for dr_amt is **numeric(15, 2)**

Anyone?

Comment: Post your database writing code please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), and [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Don't store a double value in a varchar field. Store it in a number field.

Comment: @LukasEder : SQL Server 2008.  But I found out the next day there was a small logical error independent of this conversion.  So it turns out the conversion into exponential value was not the real reason behind it.  But from now onwards I will use BigDecimal for financial data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm very much guessing that you do something like this:

```
connection.createStatement().executeUpdate(
  "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('" + myDouble + "')");
```

Don't do that for the following reasons:

- Concatenating strings will cause syntax errors
- Concatenating strings will cause SQL injection

Write your statement in a way to let JDBC handle data types:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
  "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(?)");
stmt.setDouble(1, myDouble);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

If you absolutely *must* inline your double value in your SQL string instead of using bind values, try using `BigDecimal` to serialise your double, instead:

```
new BigDecimal(myDouble).toString();
```

Since you seem to be operating on monetary values, you should change all your doubles to `BigDecimal` anyway, as `BigDecimal` is Java's best match for SQL's `DECIMAL` data type

Answer (score 4):

You should be using JDBC *prepared statements*, with *bound parameters*, e.g.

```
PreparedStatement s = c.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO mytable (myfield) VALUES (?)");
s.setDouble(1, n);
s.executeUpdate();
```

[exception handling code omitted]

The JDBC layer will ensure that your double variable is correctly sent to the database server without getting mangled.